Why do some rows of hiragana have characters with a different sound instead of making a new row?
I am sorry if this does not make sense.
In the は row, there is the ふ character, so if you want to make a "hu" sound, you must combine characters, and to make any other syllable with an "f" starting sound, you must combine with ふ。This also happens in the さ row with し and the た row with ち。So, why not just make a new row with those consonant sounds instead of putting it in with a different row? Sorry, thank you!

Are you asking why there is not a "fa fi -fu- fe fo" row of kana?

Some of it's because saying さ is "sa" and し is "shi" is just an approximation - the actual consonant sounds are actually fairly consistent in a row but the vowel pairing changes how they get matched to English sounds.

When hiragana and katakana were created, は, ひ, ふ, へ and ほ were pronounced /pa/, /pi/, /pu/, /pe/ and /po/. Some time later, pronunciation of morpheme-medial occurrences of these syllables changed to /wa/, /wi/, /u/, /we/ and /wo/ (e.g. 川{かは} /kapa/ → /kawa/). Some time later, pronunciation of morpheme-initial occurrences of these syllables changed to /ɸa/, /ɸi/, /ɸu/, /ɸe/ and /ɸo/ (e.g. 花{はな} /pana/ → /ɸana/). /ɸ/ sounds similarly to /f/, but is not exactly the same.

Probably in 18th century, pronunciation of /ɸ/ started changing to /h/ (even with ふ = /hu/), but the pattern which became standard in Standard Japanese in 19th century had ふ = /ɸu/, and /h/ in other syllables (before vowels other than /u/). However some conservative dialects preserve pronunciation of は, ひ, ふ, へ and ほ as /ɸa/, /ɸi/, /ɸu/, /ɸe/ and /ɸo/ (e.g. Izumo dialect).

When hiragana and katakana were created, either し and ち were still [si] and [ti], or creators of hiragana and katakana were aware of automatic palatalization of consonants before /i/ and considered it as allophonic.

Does this answer your question? Why doesn't Japanese have a special Katakana form for "hu"? た, ち, つ, て, and と did share the same consonant in the Japanese perception until relatively recently. People today recognize the sounds of ティ (as in "tea") and トゥ (as in "toe") in loanwords, but it was too late to invent completely new kana for them and reorganize the kana table.

@ConMan As I understand it, initial consonants really are inconsistent within the same row sometimes: さ [sa], し [ɕi]; た [ta], つ [t͡sɨ], ち [t͡ɕi]; は [ha], ふ [ɸu], ひ [çi]. I think the mainstream analysis is that there is a true phonetic difference between those consonants (although it is of course entirely predictable).

Languages change over time, and orthography often lags behind. Many orthographic conventions in English come from times before Great Vowel Shift. There is possibility that consonants in Japanese would be consistent e.g. around year 1000. However in the past, kana were often ordered in Iroha system instead of gojūon system. Last major reform of kana orthography was in 1946 (see Historical kana orthography).
